# which will render first <apex:includeScript> or <script> tag and what is the difference between them? How to use JS fucntion in Visualforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I was roaming around the internet for this question.

I want to use include jquery first then mu custom js which uses jquery.

After the above steps, I want to call a function from my custom js which will take my json data's value returned by apex.
ie. customeJSFunction(jsonValueArg)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `loadOnReady` attribute on `apex:includeScript` - meaning, that library will load only after DOM is constructed. <strike>For `script` you dont have such capability.</strike>

Also `apex:includeScript` docs:

> Multiple references to the same script are de-duplicated, making this component safe to use inside an iteration component. This might occur if, for example, you use an  inside a custom component, and then use that component inside an  iteration.

Interesting read on script tag:

- If async is present: The script is executed asynchronously with the
  rest of the page (the script will be executed while the page
  continues the parsing)
- If async is not present and defer is present: The script is executed
  when the page has finished parsing
- If neither async or defer is present: The script is fetched and
  executed immediately, before the browser continues parsing the page

Comment: For the script tag, you can use the async or defer attribute. loadOnReady simply uses defer.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks sfdcfox!!